# How to properly pitch the following phrase

Tags: phrase-requests

How can I properly pitch the following phrase.

"This connectivity stems two direct consequences"

I know there is some serious flaw in the above statement but I cannot find proper ways to express what I mean. I'll explain my thought below. (also see the image)

"Digital activities requires connectivity two things stem out of connectivity"
[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, mainly because your question is rather abstract. You could just make two sentences out of your text (with correct pluralisation): "Digital activities require connectivity. Two things stem out of connectivity," but I suspect that is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I mean the same. But the thing is this phrase does not seem very good on the face. I am not choosy about words, if the idea is explained, I can completely change my words as well !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the transitive form of the verb *stem*, which is used for phrases such as, "Stem the tide," where *stem* means to stop something from spreading or continuing. What you want is the intransitive form of *stem*. Here's a possible rephrasing that would make more sense:

"From this connectivity stem two direct consequences."

This suggests that two things stem **from** something, which is what I believe you are trying to say.